# Does Ubuntu have onboard support for dual video

Tags: video, graphics

I am looking to buy a graphics card so I can get dual monitors for my desktop.  Do I need a specific card or will any graphics card have onboard support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running here with a new nvidia gtx550. I had an old monitor laying around and tried to plug it... didn't even knew about dual monitors. And now works like a charm. Dual monitor with compiz. This is my setup in the first cube side:

[image]

My old ati radeon had two outputs too, but I was never able to make the two monitors work with extended desktop. The only think that worked was clonning the screen 1 in screen 2. It's also true than the ati was old and the nvidia is new, so might be that. Just check diferent models before you buy anything, there's plenty of results if you put "dual monitor ubuntu whatever_model_gpu" in google.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do this with ubuntu but is best to check hardware compatibility